# ViewSwitcher dragging (cf. Calendar week view / Google Talk conversations)

Tags: android, animation, view, swipe

I want to implement something like the Android Calendar week view, where you can move through the weeks -- or like the Talk app, where you can switch between conversations. In other words, I want to be able to *drag* the views, not just swipe them.

The only thing that I seem to be able to do is to switch views (with a sliding animation) *after* the swipe action. In the two examples I mentioned, the views are actually dragged, i.e. the animation shows while moving your finger on the screen.

I've been going through the Calendar source, but the classes involved are so huge, I can't make head nor tail of it.

Has anyone done something like this, or is there any (relatively concise) source available somewhere?

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe you could try to do bi-directionnal listviews? that's just an idea, maybe completely silly. Or simply do a kind of drag and drop, and when the position is between 2 values, you fix it to the middle when the finger leaves the screen?

Comment: Did you found out how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) from the android compatibility package.

[This](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) is a good place to start. This will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Indeed. At the time, however, it didn't exist (or I didn't know about it).

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the calendar code and this is what I understood:

The `WeekActivity` contains a `ViewSwitcher` that is composed of two `CalendarView`. When the user generates a scroll event, the event is detected by the `CalendarActivity` and get the X coordinate of the scroll. The current view is invalidated, which calls the `onDraw()` function of the CalendarView (the `onDraw()` method is where the grid and the events are drawn).

In `onDraw()`,  the canvas is translated using the X (`canvas.translate(x)`) and the `onDraw()` method of the other view of the ViewSwitcher is called to fill in the rest of the content.

---

I wanted to have the same behavior in my app, but I choose to use a Gallery instead and modify it to fit my need.